# Sharing Audio Files on Google drive

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, google-drive-api

I am developing a windows phone 7 application in which i am downloading some audio files,
And i want to upload those downloaded files on Google drive.
I searched but did not found any proper clue. Please suggest how to start with Google drive 
and further implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is Google Drive lib for WP7 curently but.  Google Drive APIs are universal HTTP requests and can be used on any devices and platforms.  You can construct your HTTP request by hand.    If all you want to do is upload then your looking for file insert.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert